# Getting name of file with C++ application

Tags: c++, file, file-extension

I imagine this should be relatively simple but I can't find any info about it... I am assuming I just don't know what to search for, but if anyone can help that would be great.

I have some files that I create myself and have given a custom extension. I have a C++ application that is supposed to be able to read and interpret these files.

If I right-click on one of this files, say "Open With" and select my C++ application exe, how do I the path information of the file I clicked on from within the application?

Thanks!

Comment: It'll usually be passed as a command line argument. So.. `argv[1]` maybe.

Comment: If you are using visual studio - you should be able to see the file properties in `Properties` tab usually bottom left or bottom right of the IDE.

Comment: @Rapptz           The OP wants to see the typical Windows file properties (select right-click > properties) in the IDE he is using.

Comment: @hagubear "how do I get the info of the file I clicked on from within the application?"

Comment: @Rapptz          "Info of the file" doesn't necessarily mean the file-name (ONLY). Edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

Windows will in this case run your application with the name of the supplied file as one of its command-line parameters.

```
your_application.exe clicked_file.ext
```

You probably recall that the `main()` function has a prototype that goes like

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

This version of `main()` allows you to handle command-line parameters. In your case, the name of the file parameter should be at `argv[1]`.